# Adjoint functors in 2-category theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\cal{C},\cal{D}$ be two categories. Let $F:\cal{C}\rightarrow\cal{D}$ and $G:\cal{D}\rightarrow\cal{C}$ be a pair of adjoint functors such that $F$ is left adjoint to $G$. Suppose that $\cal{D}$ admits limits. Then it is known that $G$ preserves limits in $\cal{D}$. However, is there an analogy of this statement in 2-category theory? Does right adjoint 2-functor preserve 2-limits?

Comment: Yes, with appropriate definitions this is still true and the proof is the same.